# Articles after 'going to'

Tags: definite-article

It seems sometimes speakers use **'the'** even when the noun is not definite. For example, they may say :

> *"I'm going to **the** shopping centre/beach/cinema/gym."*

While I don't know and they haven't mentioned which shopping centre/beach/cinema/gym they are going to. How can this be explained?

Answer (score 1):

Because in their mind it *has* been determined.  This is the purpose of the definite article.  It indicates the the speaker has a definite place in mind, and that place is known to the listener, either because it has been mentioned previously, or because it will be identified in the forthcoming context, or because the identity can be understood from the wider context.

When a person used "the" you should be able to answer the question "which".

> I'm going to the gym

(Which gym — The one which I'm a member of and which I go to every other day)

But we would say "I'm going to join a gym" since in that context it isn't definite. It can't be identifed as "the one which I'm a member of" but is still just "one of many".

> I'm going to the shopping centre

(Which shopping centre ­— The one in the nearby town,  the one I go to when I want to go shopping)

In some cases the "institutional definite article" is used. "The cinema" is "the place for showing movies".  There may be many particular buildings for this, but there is a single institution of "cinema".  This use is rather idiomatic, and varies between dialects. You can understand  "the beach" and "the cinema" as either "identified from context" or "refering to the type or place not a particular place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mentioned in the question that the noun is not determinable by the listener (e.g. they have just met). 

So as a general rule, are you saying that "the" shows the definition (being definite) from the speaker standpoint regardless of its specificity for the listener?